# CSS - Child Div (absolute) in parent Div (relative) not moving to bottom

Tags: css

This is my first question, so I hope it adheres to the standards. I am trying to move my child `div` to the bottom of the parent `div`. I read that the positioning of the parent `div` has to be set to `relative` and the positioning of the child `div` has to be set to `absolute`. Then, `bottom` has to be set to 0 for the child `div` to move down.

```
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
    .card {
        position:relative;
    /* Don’t change these */
        float: left;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        /* Feel free to play around with these */
        text-align: center;
        border-style: double;
        border-width: 3px;
        background: #84a0d7;
        line-height: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        /* Change the width to get a different layout */
        width: 33.33%;

    }

    .comment {
        font-size:9pt;
        color:white;
        font-family:Verdana;
        line-height:normal;
        position:absolute;

        /* Here, I set top to 0. If I change that line to bottom:0;
           the Div moves up instead of down. Could someone help me 
           figure out why that happens?                               */

        top:0;
        text-align:left;
        width: 100%;
        height:100px;    
    }

    @media (max-width:800px) {
        .card {
            width:50%;
        }

}

    @media (max-width:400px) {
        .card {
            width:100%;
        }
}

    </style>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0px">
        <h1>Best Football Players</h1>
        <div class="card">
            Messi
            <div class="comment">Undoubtedly the best in the world and most likely of all times (Sorry, Ronaldo fans)</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the height of both elements is the same, logistically that doesn't make sense given the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you have the `comment` set to same height as the `card`, so it doesn't matter if you set `top` or `bottom` to 0.

Change `.comment` like this and it will align at the bottom.

```
bottom:0;
height: auto;
```

Sample snippet

```css
    .card {
        position: relative;
    /* Don’t change these */
        float: left;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        /* Feel free to play around with these */
        text-align: center;
        border-style: double;
        border-width: 3px;
        background: #84a0d7;
        line-height: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        /* Change the width to get a different layout */
        width: 33.33%;

    }

    .comment {
        font-size:9pt;
        color:white;
        font-family:Verdana;
        line-height:normal;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        text-align:left;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;    
    }

    @media (max-width:800px) {
        .card {
            width:50%;
        }

}

    @media (max-width:400px) {
        .card {
            width:100%;
        }
}
```

```html
        <h1>Best Football Players</h1>
        <div class="card">
            Messi
            <div class="comment">Undoubtedly the best in the world and most likely of all times (Sorry, Ronaldo fans)</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes perfect sense!